# Contact form 7 add image to every single radio input

Tags: wordpress, radio-button

I am building a form using Contact Form 7 in Wordpress which has a few radio inputs. I would like to have near every single radio button a small image (some kind of label which shows a fabric texture). 
Has anyone an idea how can I achieve this?
Maybe there is some working plugins like ACF, which are compatible with CF7 or jQuery snippet which insert single html line with `<img>` tag.

I would need a layout like this one:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contact form 7 has unique id or class for every input field, you can target that class or ID to add stylings

I have done this sample to show the process, your code may be different than this

```
<input class="radio1" type="radio">
```

CSS:

```
input.radio1 {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    display: block; /* You Can remove display block, since your buttons are already stacked */
}
input.radio1:after {
    background-image: url('images/image.img');
    content: '';
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-left: 35px;
}
```

[image]

or simply you can apply the background image to that green box if you are already planning to make it look that way.

Comment: Your solution works fine for me. I was looking for something which would be based on jQuery but this is fine as well. Thank you.

Comment: This solution does not work in Firefox.  <input> elements are not supposed to have content, and therefore should not contain ::before or ::after tags either, and Firefox enforces this arbitrary rule.  I would guess that other browsers may follow suit eventually, so beware if you choose to implement images in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Wasim's solution works but if you need to make it with img tag, you can use this:

```
$(".radio-image span span").unwrap(); //Remove spans between input and label tags
$(".wpcf7-list-item-label").remove(); //Remove the label that added by Contact Form 7
$(".radio-image input+label").each(function () {
    const id = $(this).prop("for");
    $(this).parent().find("input").attr("id", id);
});
```

This is markup for Contact Form 7

```
    <div class="radio-image">                
        [radio radio-name "Value"]
        <label for="label-1"><img src="path/to/image.jpg"></label>
    </div>
```

The rest is CSS work.

```
.radio-image {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  [type="radio"] {
    display: none;

    + label {
      position: relative;

      &:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: -5px;
        left: -5px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: $white;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        z-index: 2;
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px $white;
      }
      &:after {
        content: "";
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        background: $primary-color;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 5px;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        display: none;
        z-index: 3;
      }
    }

    &:checked + label::after {
      display: block;
    }

    &:checked + label img {
      filter: grayscale(0) !important;
    }
  }
}
```